# Finding a Basis of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Consider the matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
I am trying to find a basis for $A$. From what I understand, a basis must consist of linearly independent columns that span the entire space.

Is the following set a basis:
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1\end{pmatrix}\right\}?$$

**Original question**

Let $C$ be the binary linear code with parity check matrix
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
and let $B$ be a basis for $C$. How many codewords does $B$ contain?

Answer is $2$.

Comment: Did you try to generate all column vectors from it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I did not. My basis is incorrect because the two middle terms are equal to zero. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct that it is false.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can the basis consist of one column vector?

Comment: The basis of what? The linear span of one non-zero vector is always $1$-dimensional.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut If we consider a set of each column vector of the matrix, construct a basis. Does this help?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've included the original question that will hopefully provide some more context

Comment: Ah yes, this is a very popular homework for coding theory. Just search this site!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I will continue looking. If you know of previous questions that are similar, I would love to have a read.

Comment: You're asked to find a basis for for the *code* $C$, *not* for the column space of the matrix.  The code with parity check matrix $\ H\ $ is the modulo $2$ *nullspace* of $\ H\ $, so the basis $\ B\ $ you're looking for is one for this nullspace. Every member of $\ B\ $ will be a codeword, and the number of members of $\ B\ $ is the dimension of the nullspace, which is independent of which basis you choose.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Oh! So the number of codewords in $B$ is the dimensions of the nullspace? Does this mean that it is also equal to the number of non-leading columns (assuming our matrix has full rank),  by the Rank-Nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes, although you don't need to assume that the matrix has full rank.  The [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem#Matrices)  tells you that the sum of a matrix's rank and its nullity equals its number of columns, regardless of what its rank is.